# Not able to get message from go channel

Tags: go

I am a sample for stats collection in which I have used a go channel inside a struct, logically seems correct to me but I'm not able to find the problem with below code, it just simply doesn't print values I have added.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

//StatsMessage will hold single stats entry
type StatsMessage struct {
    Name  string
    Value int64
}

//StatsCollector will hold collected stats
type StatsCollector struct {
    msgchan  chan StatsMessage
    messages []StatsMessage
    done     chan int
}

//Init will start a go routine
func (s StatsCollector) Init() {
    s.msgchan = make(chan StatsMessage)
    s.done = make(chan int)
    s.messages = make([]StatsMessage, 0)
    go s.fillMessages()
}

//AddStats adds a single stats in a Messages
func (s StatsCollector) AddStats(name string, value int64) {
    msg := StatsMessage{Name: name, Value: value}
    s.msgchan <- msg
    fmt.Println("Message added")
}

func (s StatsCollector) fillMessages() {
    fmt.Println("Filler started...")
    for {
        s.messages = append(s.messages, <-s.msgchan)
        fmt.Println("Added to messages")
    }
}

func generateStats(s *StatsCollector) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println("Generated message...")
            s.AddStats("my_first_stats", rand.Int63())
        case <-s.done:
            fmt.Println("Stop generating")
            return
        }
    }
}

func flushStats(s *StatsCollector) {
    for _, stat := range s.messages {
        fmt.Println(stat.Name, stat.Value)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := &StatsCollector{}
    s.Init()
    go generateStats(s)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    flushStats(s)
}
```

if I provide the struct fields at the time of StatsCollector object reation then it does work a bit

Comment: Use pointer receiver, all of your methods work on an empty copy of the value. https://play.golang.com/p/dcc2cFPZ_WT

Comment: @mkopriva thank you so much, that was stupid mistake I have made